# In DBT I cannot import name 'RuntimeException' from 'dbt.exceptions'

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, dbt

I tried to setup dbt on a EC2 instance, creating an conda environment:

```
conda create --name dbt-athena python=3.10
conda activate dbt-athena
conda install -c conda-forge dbt-athena-adapter
```

Then I see dbt is installed correctly:

```
dbt --version
Core:
  - installed: 1.5.1
  - latest:    1.5.2 - Update available!
```

So I tried to initialize a project:

```
dbt init gapminder
15:08:31  Running with dbt=1.5.1
The profile gapminder already exists in /home/ec2-user/.dbt/profiles.yml. Continue and overwrite it? [y/N]: y
Which database would you like to use?
[1] athena

(Don't see the one you want? https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/available-adapters)
```

But I get this error:

```
15:08:55  Encountered an error:
cannot import name 'RuntimeException' from 'dbt.exceptions' (/home/ec2-user/miniconda3/envs/dbt-athena/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dbt/exceptions.py)
15:08:55  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/miniconda3/envs/dbt-athena/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dbt/cli/requires.py", line 86, in wrapper
    result, success = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/miniconda3/envs/dbt-athena/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dbt/cli/requires.py", line 71, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/miniconda3/envs/dbt-athena/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dbt/cli/main.py", line 457, in init
    results = task.run()
  File "/home/ec2-user/miniconda3/envs/dbt-athena/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dbt/task/init.py", line 305, in run
    self.create_profile_from_target(adapter, profile_name=project_name)
  File "/home/ec2-user/miniconda3/envs/dbt-athena/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dbt/task/init.py", line 173, in create_profile_from_target
    load_plugin(adapter)
  File "/home/ec2-user/miniconda3/envs/dbt-athena/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dbt/adapters/factory.py", line 202, in load_plugin
    return FACTORY.load_plugin(name)
  File "/home/ec2-user/miniconda3/envs/dbt-athena/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dbt/adapters/factory.py", line 57, in load_plugin
    mod: Any = import_module("." + name, "dbt.adapters")
  File "/home/ec2-user/miniconda3/envs/dbt-athena/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/ec2-user/miniconda3/envs/dbt-athena/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dbt/adapters/athena/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from dbt.adapters.athena.connections import AthenaConnectionManager
  File "/home/ec2-user/miniconda3/envs/dbt-athena/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dbt/adapters/athena/connections.py", line 22, in <module>
    from dbt.exceptions import RuntimeException, FailedToConnectException
ImportError: cannot import name 'RuntimeException' from 'dbt.exceptions' (/home/ec2-user/miniconda3/envs/dbt-athena/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dbt/exceptions.py)
```

I checked up my profiles.yml file:

```
gapminder:
  outputs:
    dev:
      aws_profile_name: ec2-user
      database: awsdatacatalog
      region_name: us-east-1
      s3_data_dir: s3://mybucket/results/
      s3_staging_dir: s3://mybucket/results/
      schema: myschema
      threads: 1
      type: athena
  target: dev
```

So I can't create this project. Please, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What EC2 instance and OS are you using?

Comment: @RicardoSueiras, it's Amazon Linux, a t2.small

Answer (score 1):

This could be a dependency or utility version mismatch issue.

I got the same error after I upgraded dbt to v 1.5 or higher. However, the issue went away once I updated the snowflake adaptor:

pip install --upgrade dbt-snowflake